# Tomcat Not Listening On Port 8443

Tags: ssl, tomcat, debian

I've just set up Tomcat on a fresh Debian VM. Port 8080 over HTTP works with no issue, yet after hours of fiddling around I cannot find a way of enabling HTTPS.

I've followed the guide to generate a self-signed certificate here: [How to create a self signed SSL certificate for use with Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42541356/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-use-with-tomcat)

I've set my server.xml file up as follows:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxthreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           keystoreFile="selfsigned.jks" keystorePass="123456"
           clientAuth="false" acceptCount="100"/>
```

I've restarted Tomcat, and yet still the thing isn't listening on port 8443.

Running *netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN* shows:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      542/sshd
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      7953/java
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      7953/java
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      542/sshd
```

Even if the certificate was wrong, surely it would be listening on port 8443, no?

I've also tried copying the server.xml from this question:
[Tomcat: Trouble with SSL https connection on port 8443](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452505/tomcat-trouble-with-ssl-https-connection-on-port-8443)

Yet again, port 8443 isn't listening.
What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
I see the following error within the catalina log file:

*Caused by: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect*

I've removed and recreated the Keystore file with the same password, so I can't see why this isn't working.

My Server.xml file now looks like this:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           defaultSSLHotConfigName="qa-maintenance.company.com">
    <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
    <SSLHostConfig hostname="qa-maintenance.company.com" protocols="TLSv1.2,+TLSv1.1,+TLSv1">
        <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/keystore.jks"
                     type="RSA" KeystorePass="123456" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

Comment: If a connector fails to start Tomcat's default is to log it and keep going. Check your logs (especially `catalina.<date>.log`) for any errors concerning your TLS connector.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz - Thanks for that. I've updated the question with the issue.

Comment: The property's name is `certificateKeystorePassword`, not `KeystorePass` (cf. [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support_-_Certificate))

Comment: Thanks, @PiotrP.Karwasz. That's resolved the issue! If you add it as an answer I'll mark it accordingly :)

Comment: I voted to close this question, since it was caused by a typo.